# How to repeat xml element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I have created the code to load elements from a xml file. But it does not load repeated values in xml file. It only loads one element, others are not loading.
Herewith attached an example.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"data.xml",
        dataType:"xml",
        success:showdata
    });
});

function showdata(xml){
    xml = $(xml).children();

     $(xml).children().each(function () {
        let tag = $(this).prop("tagName");                   
        let to = $(this).find("to").text();
        let from =$(this).find("from").text();
        let heading = $(this).find("heading").text();
        let list = $(this).find("list").text();
        let body =$(this).find("body").text();

        let html = `<div class="col-md-4"  id="random">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                      <a href="#${tag}"><p>${to}</p>
                      <p>${from}</p>
                      <p>${heading}</p>
                      <p>${body}</p></a>
                    </div>
                    </div>`;

        let popup = `<div id="${tag}" class="overlay">
                <div class="popup">
                    <h6>${heading}</h6>
                    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
                    <ul><li>${list}</li></ul>
                </div>
            </div>`;

        $("#xmldata").append(html);
        $("#popup").append(popup);

    });
}
```

http://next.plnkr.co/edit/MVwJnBHypBFvg2Lk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw in your code you are using anchor tag and it is always pointing to **#note**. I have just append index number and Now it is perfect.

Please Change this line

```
$(xml).children().each(function (index,item) {
    let tag = $(this).prop("tagName")+index;
```

I have also updated list which was not binding as a li. Now check it will work for you

Complete Code is as follows

```
function showdata(xml){
    xml = $(xml).children();

     $(xml).children().each(function (index,item) {
        let tag = $(this).prop("tagName")+index;                   
        let to = $(this).find("to").text();
        let from =$(this).find("from").text();
        let heading = $(this).find("heading").text();
        let list = $(this).find("list");
        let body =$(this).find("body").text();

        let html = `<div class="col-md-4"  id="random">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                      <a href="#${tag}"><p>${to}</p>
                      <p>${from}</p>
                      <p>${heading}</p>
                      <p>${body}</p></a>
                    </div>
                    </div>`;
                    var listStr="";
                    list.each((index,item)=>{
                            listStr+="<li>"+item.innerHTML+"</li>"
                        }) 

        let popup = `<div id="${tag}" class="overlay">
                <div class="popup">
                    <h6>${heading}</h6>
                    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
                    <ul>`+listStr+`</ul>
                </div>
            </div>`;

        $("#xmldata").append(html);
        $("#popup").append(popup);

    });


}
```

Comment: It is not appearing with bullet points and also it displaying as a paragraph. I need to display it as a list.

Comment: Also listing is displaying good. There was the problem. Your node contains list of sting in list object and You are not evaluating as a list. Thats why I have created list separatly and binded in that

Comment: ```var listStr="";
                    list.each((index,item)=>{
                            listStr+="<li>"+item.innerHTML+"</li>"
                        }) ```

Comment: It is working now, Thank you for your support. But there is an issue that, when click a thumbnail in second node it showing first node list items. I need to show each and separate list items when click the thumbnails.